# I've some 40,000 records in my table and I want to remove the last to digits for all the records in a column

Tags: oracle11g

My data is like below :

```
2272522520
2272523235
2272525435
2272525437
2272525439
2272525443
2272525444
2272551733
```

I want to remove the last digit for all the rows in that column. Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What datatype is the column? Are they all the same length?

Comment: @AlexK. : Datatype is number. Yes all are of the same length.

Answer (score 2):

If your column is of number type:

```
update your_table
set your_column = trunc(your_column/10);
```

If it's varchar2:

```
update your_table
set your_column = substr(your_column, 1, length(your_column)-1);
```